# Symfony Multiple Databases

Tags: php, database, symfony

I'm not asking you to help me with a code purpose, but for an advice of how to do what I've got to do.

Since a few weeks, i'm developing a web application based on the symfony3 framework, and now, I have to modify what I did because my boss wants me to open the solution on multiple "groups". In fact, the group will correspond with a database which will be the group's content for the application.

I explain with a schema:

Login page -> login / password / group

If GROUP = A, database = db_group_a (for exemple)
If GROUP = B, database = db_group_b (..)

I dont know if it's clear, but here's what I have to do, and I really dont know how to do it with Symfony (In simple PHP, I would do it quite simply, but Symfony makes me ask you). If you could help me, it would be awesome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In symfony you can define multiple databases like this:

```
$container->loadFromExtension('doctrine', array(
    'dbal' => array(
        'default_connection' => 'default',
        'connections' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'driver'   => '%database_driver%',
                'host'     => '%database_host%',
                'port'     => '%database_port%',
                'dbname'   => '%database_name%',
                'user'     => '%database_user%',
                'password' => '%database_password%',
                'charset'  => 'UTF8',
            ),
            'group_a' => array(
                'driver'   => '%database_driver2%',
                'host'     => '%database_host2%',
                'port'     => '%database_port2%',
                'dbname'   => '%database_name2%',
                'user'     => '%database_user2%',
                'password' => '%database_password2%',
                'charset'  => 'UTF8',
            ),
            'group_b' => array(
                'driver'   => '%database_driver2%',
                'host'     => '%database_host2%',
                'port'     => '%database_port2%',
                'dbname'   => '%database_name2%',
                'user'     => '%database_user2%',
                'password' => '%database_password2%',
                'charset'  => 'UTF8',
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Now, once you logged in and found out, what group is the user privileged to, you can set that in your session and add as a parameter to queries similar to this:

```
$allowed_db = 'group_a';
$customers = $this->get('doctrine')
            ->getRepository('AcmeCustomerBundle:Customer', $allowed_db)
            ->findAll();
```

Comment: *Notice: since I don't have a running Symphony copy on my PC right now, the code example in not tested and taken from the web as example.*

Comment: Hey, thanks, it looks awesome ! I thought it was only in the config.yml that we had to manage de databases. Well, where do i need to write a code like yours? (the first one)

Comment: I understand, thanks :) (is it possible to open a room to discuss? I have a few more questions, really quickly)

Comment: Sure, go ahead and ask

Comment: can you create the room? I think I can't yet because of my level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112668/discussion-between-dainis-abols-and-shqnks).